# Drop Down Selection and pulling out data

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

[image]

I have got this in my current sheet, and I have different sheets for Merchant id.. Merchant id above is a drop down(1072,1074,1027,etc list of these numbers) 
the other sheets have got the same format of table as above.. 
What formula should I use to pull the complete sheet from individual sheet of merchant id on selecting any particular merchant id from drop down? Can anyone please help?

Details of the Image sheet one is the main sheet I am working on, and sheet two is the data I will be having and which I need to show in sheet one,

1072, 1074, 1016, 1017 the drop down content is the merchant id I have shown in sheet 2 with blue ink.. Help me out with this..

Comment: Can you format your table so its makes sense, and explain what you mean by "pull the complete sheet from individual sheet"? What is your desired outcome?

Comment: hi just added the images of my excel sheets, there are three charts of data which i need to show in my main sheet 1, It goes like if i select any merchant id from drop down it automatically goes to the respective tab and picks up the value and shows the results.. there are three data charts and i will be making three similar drop down for them.. i hope my query is clear now

Comment: i am unable to add the main sheet .. lemme know when you can view and save the sheet i have attached, i will add the main sheet after that

Comment: Can't see anything.

Comment: Use `=INDIRECT()` to reference a worksheet.

Comment: Thanks Tim for your time, though I used this formulae.. which worked for two merchant id .. i have to make the same for other 4 i have.. I have used- =IF(JJ3=1072,(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(JJ3,'1072'!A22:I22,2,0),"no")),(IF(JJ3=1074,IF(JJ3=1074,(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(JJ3,'1074'!A22:I22,2,0),"yes"))))))

Comment: If your data is organised the same for each sheet you can use `=INDIRECT(JM3&"!A1")`, from your picture example this would show the data in cell A1 in sheet 1072.

Comment: Hey, I constructed this formula using INDIRECT which is great -- IF(AND(JV3=1072,KE2="Bottom 20 performing  GEO(No Sale)"),INDIRECT(JV3&"!B4"),(IF(AND(JV3=1074,KE2="Bottom 20 performing  GEO(No Sale)"),INDIRECT(JV3&"!B4"),(IF(AND(JV3=1029,KE2="Bottom 20 performing  GEO(No Sale)"),INDIRECT(JV3&"!B4"),(IF(AND(JV3=1016,KE2="Bottom 20 performing  GEO(No Sale)"),INDIRECT(JV3&"!B4"),IF(AND(JV3=1017,KE2="Bottom 20 performing  GEO(No Sale)"),INDIRECT(JV3&"!B4"),0))))))))

Comment: Why not just `=IF(KE2="Bottom 20 performing GEO(No Sale)", INDIRECT($J$V3&IB4), "")

Comment: Another issue is, ifu check the diagram, you can see there is drop down which gives option 1. Bottom 20 performing GEO(No Sale) 2. Above 20% ROI
 3. Below 20% ROI ,,,, help me out with this one Tim, what modification should i make in above formulae

Comment: For what? I just rewrote your formula, what are the conditions for `Above 20% ROI` or `Below....` ?

Comment: my issue is resolved though, and thankyou for introducing me to INDIRECT made my formulae way easier.. Thanks Tim

Comment: Added a new image which shows sheet from where i am picking up the data ..

Comment: You will have to change cell references but try and manipulate this `=INDIRECT($JV$3&IF(KE2="Bottom 20 performing GEO(No Sale)",IB4,IF(KE2="Above 20% ROI", IB4, IF(KE2="Below 20% ROI", IB4,""))))`